How can I retrieve all Ethereum transfers from a transaction?
I'm trying to extract all Ethereum transfers from a given transaction. Some transactions send transfers to block builders, while others may involve different recipients or actions. What is the best way to obtain detailed information about these transfers within a single transaction?

I'm not sure if you mean the Ethereum transfers of native ETH or ERC20.

If it's ETH transfer, you can use JSON-RPC trace_transaction, you can filter the results to focus on the traces of "callType": "call" involving ETH transfers (where value > 0).
example: https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/trace-transaction

"action": {
    "callType": "call",
    "from": "0x83806d539d4ea1c140489a06660319c9a303f874",
    "gas": "0x1a1f8",
    "input": "0x",
    "to": "0x1c39ba39e4735cb65978d4db400ddd70a72dc750",
    "value": "0x7a16c911b4d00000"
}


If it's ERC20 transfer, you can use JSON-RPC eth_getTransactionReceipt to get the event log (including ERC-20 transfers), but not internal ETH transfers. examples:
ERC20: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/5.x/api/token/erc20#IERC20-Transfer-address-address-uint256-
WETH: https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2#code

such as Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value)(ERC-20) or Transfer(address indexed src, address indexed dst, uint wad)(WETH) events.

Yes i was talking about ETH transfer. Thank you so much, this is very comprehensive.

It should be noted that in the opcodes of Ethereum EVM, in addition to the CALL opcode, which is the most common one that can transfer ETH, there are other opcodes (although rarely used) that can also cause the transfer of ETH:


CALLCODE (0xf2)


DELEGATECALL (0xf4)


SELFDESTRUCT (0xff)


(The comment is too short and I can't write the function of each opcode)
Therefore, it is recommended that you decide how to analyze the most comprehensive results based on the contract you are using.

Hey! Thank you again for this pretty information. Interesting, can you suggest some solution that i can implement for that ? If it's not lot asked of course!

response, _ := traceTxETH(ctx, txHash)

for _, v := range response.Result {
    if v.Action.CallType == "call" && v.Action.Value != "0x0" {
        // ...do what u want to do
    }
}

func traceTxETH(_ context.Context, txHash string) (*JsonrpcResponse, error) {
    url := "https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/your-api-key"
    request := JsonrpcRequest{ID: 1, JSONRPC: "2.0", Method: "trace_transaction", Params: []string{txHash}}
    // ...
    res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    // ...
}


hey, hope you're doing good. this is little confusing, can you instead just explain me what you're doing ? are you counting the opcode ? or what exactly?

I'm sorry that this comment cannot be formatted, which makes the content look a bit messy.
This is a Go code that retrieves all native transfer information by calling trace-transaction. If you format it in an editor such as vscode, you should be able to roughly see the effect.
